# Case statement in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am pretty new in SQL and have a question regarding a football database with the following tables:

```
Create Table Team(
TId char(3) Primary Key,                       // One example for a TId is "GER". It is an abbrevation for the country
Country varchar(50) Not Null,
Coach varchar(50) Not Null
)

Create Table Match(
MId Integer Primary Key,                      // Every match has an ID
Date date Null,
Stadium varchar(100) Not Null,
Team1 char(3) Not Null,
Team2 char(3) Not Null,
Foreign Key(Team1) references Team(TId),
Foreign Key(Team2) references Team(TId)
);

Create Table Goal(
MId Integer Null,
TId char(3) Null,
Player varchar(100) Not Null,
Minute Integer Null,
Primary Key(MId, Minute),
Foreign Key(MId) references Match(MId),
Foreign Key(TId) references Team(TId)
);
```

I need to write a SQL query that gives me a back a list of all matches with the date, the stadium and the number of goals both teams scored. It should be something like

```
Select date, stadium, Team1, Count(Goals Team1), Team2, Count(Goals Team2) 

From match

...
```

I tried to start to count the goals for one team first and wanted to use a case statement but did not come that far:

```
Select s.SId, s.Team1,
Case When s.SId IN (Select distinct SId From Tor) Then Count(t.SId) 
Else "Not In"   
End As text
From Spiel s, Tor t, Team te
Where s.SId = t.SId
Group by s.SId
```

I'd be pleased if you have any idea how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT Match_id, SUM(Team_Id = {team 1}),  SUM(Team_Id = {team 2}) FROM (Goals GROUP BY Match_id`.

Comment: What is your version of Mysql?

Comment: You have a table called match? I don't believe you.

Comment: My version is 8.0.18

Comment: And well, my table is not called "match" that's right. I translated it. You can call it "game" or something like that if you want ^^

Comment: And Akina, thanks for your answer, but I am sorry, I am not really sure how I am supposed to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CTE` to return the total goals for each match and team.
Then join `Match` to 2 copies of `Team` and 2 copies of the `CTE`:

```
with cte as (
  select mid, tid, count(*) goals
  from Goal
  group by mid, tid
)  
select m.date, m.stadium,
  t1.tid team1, coalesce(c1.goals, 0) goals_1,
  t2.tid team2, coalesce(c2.goals, 0) goals_2
from `Match` m
inner join Team t1 on t1.tid = m.team1
inner join Team t2 on t2.tid = m.team2
left join cte c1 on c1.mid = m.mid and c1.tid = m.team1
left join cte c2 on c2.mid = m.mid and c2.tid = m.team2
```